# Finite/Infinite Impulse Response filters

Tags: image-processing, filters, finite-impulse-response, infinite-impulse-response, edge-detection

Most image filters are of finite extension (which correspond to Finite Impulse Response in 1 dimension), like Laplacian, Canny, Gaussian... Instead of being of infinite extension (IIR in 1D). Why is this the case? Wouldn't it theoretically produce inaccurate results?

Answer (score 2):

The Laplacian is a second derivative, which, to calculate precisely, is infinite in extension i all dimensions. A Gaussian has infinite support in all dimensions as well; the Canny operator is built from a Gaussian.

So all examples you quote *actually* are IIR, but are often approximated (or ruthlessly truncated) to be of finite length.

That indeed produces approximate results.

But your image is finite, anyway, and noisy. Operations performed on it need to finish, and you don't need all the precision for most applications.